# What happens when a metal piece is inserted into a live inductor connected in series with a resistance and DC voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance

Suppose after the metal piece is inserted, effective inductance becomes n times the initial value. It is meant to have been pushed in abruptly, what is the current through the circuit just after the insertion? The inductor is assumed to be ideal with no internal resistance.

In an unrelated situation, where a choke coil (inductor with internal resistance)is connected in parallel with a resistance and both being parallel to DC voltage, If the DC voltage is abruptly cut off from them, the current has to remain constant through the wire containing the inductor as Energy can't instantaneously vanish (after which a decay circuit would set up), can the same principle be applied here?